# Create Workforce Integration using the graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am using this endpoint in POSTMAN: Endpoint: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamwork/workforceIntegrations

with requst body
Request body:

```json
{
    "apiVersion": 1,
    "displayName": "samplename",
    "encryption": {
        "protocol": "sharedSecret",
        "secret": "someescretvalueasper the doc"
    },
    "isActive": true,
    "supportedEntities": "shift",
    "url": "sampleurl.com"
}
```

I have followed all steps as mentioned in the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/workforceintegration-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

however I am getting this error

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "{\"error\":{\"title\":\"Something went wrong\",\"externalErrorMessage\":\"Bad Request\",\"externalSource\":\"ShiftBookingsFlow\",\"externalImageLink\":null,\"externalData\":null,\"code\":\"BadRequest\",\"message\":\"Sorry your change couldn’t be completed.\",\"details\":[],\"innererror\":{\"code\":\"WorkforceIntegrationError\"}}}",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-12-18T23:47:36",
            "request-id": "d8e370a1-1d63-4137-9b49-07c74df6861b",
            "client-request-id": "d8e370a1-1d63-4137-9b49-07c74df6861b"
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong over here?

I expect a 200 Ok response but it is giving 400 bad request.

Is there any pre-requirsite to this API?

Comment: We also tried to repro this issue and also got same error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl66U.png  We are checking with engineering team and will get back to you once we have any update. Thanks!

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT Thank you for trying this out., We will wait for your next update since this is v1.0 , hoping to get this resolved sooner.

Comment: We have raised a bug for the same and engineering team is looking into it. We will inform you once we get any further update. Thanks!

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT thank you for keeping us posted.

Comment: We are checking the status of the bug with engineering team. We will inform you once we have any update. Thanks!

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT thank you so much for keeping us posted, appreciate all your support.

Comment: Could you please share the Workforce Integration URL for callbacks from the Shifts service?